# I am confused by SQL select from where in group by having

Tags: sql, select, group-by, where-clause, having

[![enter image description here][1]][1]now say I have a database, where there is a table `kits_parts_needed`, and I need to figure out what kit I have parts for, there are fields in this table that relate directly back to the inventory table, `fk_inventory_key` and `fk_inventory_key_for_parts`, I have a user scan some barcodes and those barcodes give me keys. I am then able to check this list against the database and hopefully come back with 1 kit. Here is the SQL.

```
SELECT fk_inventory_key
FROM Kits_Parts_Needed
WHERE 
 fk_inventory_Key_For_Parts IN ('7F983531-7AF8-4F10-A87C-EC555FA51BDB',
'B7FAEB96-21E2-44D5-93B1-ECE4545996FF')
GROUP BY fk_inventory_key
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fk_inventory_Key_For_Parts) = 2;
```

now for some reason this code works as this:
it selects the `fk_inventory_key` from `Kits_Parts_Needed` where the `fk_inventory_key_For_Parts` is in the list of keys I have now accrued.

I am then grouping by `fk_inventory_Key` and using the having function because I want this to be related to both keys I have in my list. And it works. I have tested this on numerous kits, and it always comes back to the right kit.

Now my problem. The way the code is written you would think it would select these kits where the `parts = part1` OR `part2` and then it would only go and verify that these returned by the where clause have at least 2 relations NOT that those two relations match that which is in the `IN` clause... however that is exactly how it seems to work.

Can someone please explain to me how this is working as I don't think it really should be... or maybe I have a happy accident and it has just worked on the 5 kits I have tested it on.

I have tried removing the group by having and get:

```
C4520143-3F5C-4433-AA9B-41550103D71C
C4520143-3F5C-4433-AA9B-41550103D71C
46C42E3A-D7A3-4FA9-83B1-A3CA93395BF3
```

if I only have the group by and having I get:

```
0CDE77A4-C626-44F6-8B19-71C440827FC8
1AC67209-62C5-4E70-B218-DFF9608754E5
2005C859-F917-4790-BF4A-6184794020AF
208C3784-FD95-438D-9F5F-F4DECF376A03
24E8B3AA-0489-4C19-8C86-3DEE1173E9BA
28C562E3-3C89-4853-8616-36CD712D3838
2B48A4EA-821C-4F98-9E06-43E53057C9F9
3CE723D8-134F-4556-8DD1-EED4C5AEA4AB
6DF89B22-F25D-4C68-BDF7-773231F80A4D
7309666C-64EB-42BB-B712-8E040ED000EF
77FA3EF7-57B1-472B-A2EC-010AE40C52F7
78E32FB5-6FBF-490C-9314-37AF1AEA27D6
8DCCBD1A-37A9-4D15-86B0-3E9D30A18C02
9472BB5F-6562-4CBA-BBC2-6A4E14458D9B
94D92945-1D96-4D13-A4EC-885FF85804AC
A67C4C3C-D881-4251-80EB-AD04217B5801
C6A916B3-D3F9-4E83-B271-4F01863E9A6B
ECCE496C-F7F1-4D86-8FBE-EA6ED70A69C9
```

when I have both in there, I get:

```
C4520143-3F5C-4433-AA9B-41550103D71C
```

which is the correct answer, but why?

TO ADD FURTHER CONTEXT:
now maybe it is because this is all in the same table, my question is why is the having implicitly checking to make sure the example 2 values in the list match those that are in the in clause. To test I created another very simple table, Testing_SQL which has the following fields:

Customer_ID, Order_ID, and Product_ID

and the following example data:

[image]

now... if you have the following SQL:

```
SELECT                Customer_ID
FROM                  Testing_SQL
WHERE                 Product_ID
IN                    (1,5)
GROUP BY              Customer_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID) = 2
```

OK... now here is where I get messed up, if you look at what the where clause should return, it returns 101 and 102.
this is ok!
group by, Works great!
Having? well if you look both 101, and 102, have purchased multiple things, so if you are counting distinct product_ID both have technically 3, but at least 2. why is this implicitly re-checking the where clause? because it only returns 101! the one that have purchased 1 AND 5.

Comment: can you add the sample data you are basing your assumptions on please? Basically the `Kits_Parts_Needed` table with the data of the columns `fk_inventory_key` and `fk_inventory_Key_For_Parts`.

Comment: For each `fk_inventory_key`, and considering only those two `fk_inventory_Key_For_Parts` values, count up the distinct `fk_inventory_Key_For_Parts` values. If the result is not 2 then ignore. So that is the same as saying: the number of *distinct* `fk_inventory_Key_For_Parts` must be the same as the nnumber of values in the `IN`, and so all of them must be present, per grouping.

Comment: yes that is what I am saying, there are two values returned by the where clause that have at least 2 distinct relationships to part keys... but only one of them has the relation TO both of the part keys specified because the where in clause is an OR relationship. somehow I am observing the having clause almost go and re-evaluate the where clause to make sure the distinct relation is in that list switching it to an AND. which doesn't make sense to me. logically if it was first as the where refining the list returned. the having, assuming it was just finding ones of the 3 returned, should find 2

Comment: but it finds 1 which would only be the case if it were examining where the distinct count of the part keys is matching that of the list.

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: The "example data" is still an image. Our markdown supports formatting text as a table. I can't follow what the problem is - please create a [mcve] on something like https://dbfiddle.uk and put a link to it in your question plus details of the difference between what your query returns and what you want returned

Comment: The connection is that you're filtering down to two specific keys and then you're requiring that two *distinct* keys be present in anything that gets output. If you needed to add a third key then you'd also have to change the comparison to `= 3`.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please clarifiy via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you missunderstood the logic. Let's look at your last data step by step. First the data:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl ( CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID ) AS
        ( Select 101, 100, 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 101, 101, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 101, 102, 5 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 103, 5 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 104, 6 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 105, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 106, 7 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 107, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 108, 2 From Dual 
        )
```

If we select all the rows from the sample data that have PRODUCT_ID IN(1, 5)

```sql
Select  * 
From    tbl
Where   PRODUCT_ID IN(1, 5)
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
CUSTOMER_ID   ORDER_ID PRODUCT_ID
----------- ---------- ----------
        101        100          1
        101        102          5
        102        103          5 */
```

the resultset above means that all other rows for this Select statement doesn't exist and whatever else we add to this code will be dealing just with those three rows, So, if we select just CUSTOMER_ID column...

```sql
Select  CUSTOMER_ID 
From    tbl
Where   PRODUCT_ID IN(1, 5)
```

```sql
/*
CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
        101
        101
        102 */
```

... we got customers from same three rows. Now if we GROUP BY we should get one row per customer ...

```sql
Select CUSTOMER_ID  
From tbl
Where PRODUCT_ID IN(1, 5)
Group By CUSTOMER_ID
/*
CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
        101
        102 */
```

Before we use HAVING clause we will put Count() aggregation in Select...

```sql
Select CUSTOMER_ID, Count(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) "CNT"
From tbl
Where PRODUCT_ID IN(1, 5)
Group By CUSTOMER_ID
/*
CUSTOMER_ID        CNT
----------- ----------
        101          2
        102          1 */
```

this is now prety obvious that Customer Id HAVING 2 DISTINCT PRODUCT_IDs is 101. Moving that count into HAVING clause is just another condition to fetch the row or not...

```sql
Select CUSTOMER_ID
From tbl
Where PRODUCT_ID IN(1, 5)
Group By CUSTOMER_ID
HAVING  Count(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) = 2
/*
CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
        101 */
```

Now if you look at the resultset of the first Select:

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
CUSTOMER_ID   ORDER_ID PRODUCT_ID
----------- ---------- ----------
        101        100          1
        101        102          5
        102        103          5 */
```

there is customer 101 with products 1 and 5 and customer 102 with just product 5. So your result is OK - CUSTOMER_ID with two Distinct products under where condition as in the question is 101